# Firebase Cloud Functions Python - Cannot Add Dependencies

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using python cloud functions in my firebase project. After initializing cloud functions, adding `firebase-admin` to the `requirements.txt` file worked, and I could test with `firebase emulators:start` and also successfully deploy with `firebase deploy --only functions`.

The issue is when I try to add other packages. I added `tldextract` to `requirements.txt` and put `import tldextract` in `main.py` which causes

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tldextract'

127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2023 00:24:10] "GET /__/functions.yaml HTTP/1.1" 500 -

⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to parse build specification
```

when I run `firebase emulators:start` or `firebase deploy --only functions`. It also seems like the `venv` folder is not being updated.

I tried activating the venv and `pip install -r requirements.txt` which made the local execution work with `firebase emulators:start`, BUT after redeploying the functions, they're stilling failing in the cloud.

I tried this with different packages to make sure it's not just this one specific package. But adding other pip packages to `requirements.txt` and importing them in `main.py` failed for all packages that I tested.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked with the suggestion in this [Github Link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/issues/92#issuecomment-1549153623)

Comment: Thank you, @SandeepVokkareni, this is also very helpful. For local packages, the import only works for me inside functions or with the workaround from the issue. BUT, this doesn't solve my problem with pip packages.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? The python firebase functions require minimum python 3.10 and above. Make sure you are using python 3.10 and above as recommended in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime).

Comment: I'm using Python 3.11 (2nd Gen)

Comment: As the python is in preview for firebase functions hence there might be chances that issue may happen and no documentation is available. Feel free to contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: Also try explicitly giving the python version while installing the `tldextract` dependency by using the command `python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solved the issue for me:

Delete the `venv` folder created by `firebase init functions`.

Create a new one as follows:

```
python3.11 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install --upgrade pip
python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now deploy with `firebase deploy --only functions`

Comment: is this really the thing to do? It doesn' feel too good :-)

Comment: Would it work if a completely new virtual environment were used instead of `venv`, and can firebase use e.g. `new_venv` or is the virtual environment's name expected to be `venv`?

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:

Add your dependencies to the `requirements.txt` and run `firebase init functions` again. This will install all dependencies. It worked for me with local execution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem is, that the Python cloud Functions is in an virtual enviroment. But if you just run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

it will install just on your system and NOT in the virtual enviroment.

So the right way to do it is:

1: check if virtualenv is installed on your system if not:

```
pip install virtualenv --user
```

2: Now you have to activate the virtuel enviroment. Therefore go in the right directory and run following command. For me:

```
cd ./functions
```

Windows:

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

Linux and Mac:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

You should see the change inside the terminal.

3: NOW you can run pip and it works

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

4: If you want to deactivate the venv just run

```
deactivate
```

in the console.

5: Restart the emulator

This should be the right way! Hope i could help :D