# Can't use pandas in firebase function

Tags: python, pandas, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to use pandas in my google cloud-firebase function, i installed it using:

```
python3 pip install pandas
```

and imported it in my function:

```
import pandas as pd
```

but, in the firebase emulator i 'm having this error:

```
[2023-09-26 00:04:58,056] ERROR in app: Exception on /__/functions.yaml [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_functions/private/serving.py", line 122, in get_functions_yaml
    functions = get_functions()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_functions/private/serving.py", line 40, in get_functions
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".../main.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2023 00:04:58] "GET /__/functions.yaml HTTP/1.1" 500 -

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2023 00:04:58] "GET /__/quitquitquit HTTP/1.1" 200 -

/bin/sh: line 1: 11771 Terminated: 15          python3.11 ".../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_functions/private/serving.py"
```

`import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

I checked if pandas installed correctly, testing in a jupyter notebook this simple code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            "Name": [
                "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",
                "Allen, Mr. William Henry",
                "Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth",
            ],
            "Age": [22, 35, 58],
            "Sex": ["male", "male", "female"],
        }
)
print(df.head(2))
```

and it looks to be fine:

[image]

Also add pandas in the dependence in the "requirements.txt" but the error still the same

```
# version 1, didn't work
firebase_functions~=0.1.0
pandas~=2.0.0

# version 2, also didn't work
firebase_functions~=0.1.0
pandas
```

I google it for several hours but i can't find what I'm missing or what should i do to fix it.

Please someone send me a lifesaver.

Thank you!!

Comment: Is the Jupyter notebook looking at the same venv where you ran the rest of the scripts? How did you install pandas for the notebook?

Comment: I don´t think the jupyter notebook is pointing a the project's venv. I installed pandas from the terminal (pip install pandas), and i checked that the jupyter's kernel (3,11) were the same for the python's function.

Comment: Tired the approach mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76502417/3068190)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77103883/how-to-import-a-library-in-python-for-firebase-functions

@samthecodingman is right , used same approach for my case with PyMuPDF